# Arguments and subclassing

Tags: python, inheritance, arguments, subclassing

Consider a rectangle and a square. If we treat them as objects it is clearly evident that a square can inherit most or all of its properties from a rectangle, since a square is a special case of a rectangle. The only restriction is that a square must have similar side lengths.

Take a look at this very basic implementation.

```
class Rectangle(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_area(self):
        return self.x * self.y


class Square(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.x != self.y:
            raise ValueError("x and y must be equal.")
```

Type-checking is avoided for simplicity. I used `args` and `kwargs` inorder to make sure that the subclass(es) will be future proof. I am, however, not sure if I am doing it right. `Rectangle` class' `__init__` might add more arguments in the future.

The question is, if x and y must be equal, why ask for both of them in the first place? Shouldn't there be only one of them? The current inheritance scheme has this restriction - the user is forced to enter x and y. How can this problem be solved. Turning x and y in to keyword arguments is not a solution, since no defaults (or `None`) are allowed.

Comment: Attempting to define `Square` as a subclass of `Rectangle` is a classic violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) precisely because of this issue.

Comment: @chepner: Although, as the article notes, that depends on what the API of the class is.  If modifying the dimensions after creation is not a supported operation, then there's no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class Square(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x, x)
        if self.x != self.y:
            raise ValueError("x and y must be equal.")
```

If you want to add `*args` and `**kwargs` you can.  However, as an aside, this will not make anything "future proof" if you pass the `*args` and `**kwargs` to `Rectangle`, because `Rectangle` does not accept them.

Comment: Probably no need to check if you're setting it yourself :-)

Comment: @ReutSharabani: The check might still make sense as an `assert`, since if it fails, something has gone fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: The original code is presumably doing the check to make sure the superclass did the right thing.